# Changing one OLEObjects SourceName changes others on different sheets

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am having an issue with picture link OLEobjects in Excel 2007.

I have an Excel workbook (wb1) that has about 100 worksheets in it. 
Each worksheet has a couple of picture links in it that connect to a row of cells 
in another workbook (wb2).

When someone inserts a new row to wb2 the picture link in wb1 displays the wrong info. I can change the SourceName of the picture link OLEobject and have it display the correct info which is great, but when I do this it changes the sourcename of other picture links on other worksheets in the same workbook. Does there a way around this?

```
Dim s As OLEObject

For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
ws.Activate
currCount = 1
For Each s In ws.OLEObjects
    s.Select        
    'skip first row because it's the header
    If Not s.SourceName Like "*R1C*" Then       
            showRow = getRow
            newRow = Replace(rowCol, rowColSplit(0), "R" & showRow)
            s.AutoUpdate = False
            s.SourceName = Replace(s.SourceName, rowCol, newRow)
            s.Update
Next
```

Comment: Are the `OLEObject`s linked, or are they embedded? If they're linked, they're all going to point to the same thing.

Comment: They are linked. I was manually able to change the linked formula to specific separate rows in excels top formula bar for each picture link, so I figured that changing it via VBA would be the same.